# Azure Function App - how do I know what is the runtime stack after it is created

Tags: azure-functions

I created a new Azure Function App on with Windows as OS and .NET 6 Runtime stack.

[image: Create Function App With Windows OS]

And here is the summary.

[image: Create Function App Summary]

So now the question is, **how do I verify that the run time stack is indeed .net 6.**. I am trying to automate this with Terraform, and so once this is created, I just want to verify.

I checked every where, I am not able to see .net 6 any where.

For example, here in the overview it shows Rumtime Version as 4.9.0.18814. I dont think this is what I am looking for.

[image: Azure Function App overview]

The general settings also does not show it.

[image: General Settings in Azure function app]

Answer (score 3):

I realize that this response is late to the game, but I just ran across it and actually stumbled upon the answer while browsing around one of our function apps. This may be different than when the OP asked the question, and may be different at the time you're reading this, but as of today, you can confirm you the runtime stack selection as set when creating the function app on the overview page and selecting the Properties tab. You can see this by following this link to see a screenshot:
[Screenshot of Azure function app showing runtime stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/halMa.png)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use Azure CLI like this:

**Linux Function**

```
az functionapp show -n my-func -g my-rg --query "siteConfig.linuxFxVersion"

NODE|14
```

Comment: I see windowsFxVersion as null when I query using az functionapp show -n my-func -g my-rg. Am I missing something?

Comment: hmm you are right... this doesnt reliably work for Windows Functions. I'll need to see if I find a different path later

Answer (score 0):

you can get it below.

You need to go to your function app and then click on configuration. then in the Application settings tab, you need to click the Show values button and see the value of the variable `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME`. In my case its .Net core (C#)

[image]